# getting average of average depending on a column?

Tags: sql

I have a query where I get the average in each row and showing the employee.
I would like it to show the average for EACH employee. meaning I would like to average all the row with the same employee.

How would I be able to accomplish this?

This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT AVG(rating)
    FROM (VALUES 
        (cast(c.rating1 as Float)), 
        (cast(c.rating2 as Float)), 
        (cast(c.rating3 as Float)), 
        (cast(c.rating4 as Float)), 
        (cast(c.rating5 as Float))
    ) AS v(rating)
    WHERE v.rating > 0
) avg_rating, employee
From CSEReduxResponses c
Where 
     month(c.approveddate)= 6
AND  year(c.approveddate)=2014
```

Below I have some sample data I created:

```
 create table CSEReduxResponses (rating1 int, rating2 int, rating3 int, rating4 int, rating5 int,
                                approveddate datetime,employee int)

insert into CSEReduxResponses (rating1 , rating2  ,rating3 , rating4 , rating5 ,
                                approveddate, employee )
values 
(5,4,5,1,4,'2014-06-18',1),
(5,4,5,1,4,'2014-06-18',1),
(5,4,5,1,0,'2014-06-18',1),
(5,4,0,1,4,'2014-06-18',2),
(5,4,5,1,4,'2014-06-18',2),
(5,4,0,1,4,'2014-06-18',3),
(5,0,5,4,4,'2014-06-18',3),
(5,4,5,0,0,'2014-06-18',3);
```

Comment: Grouping the data by employee should do it - have you tried that yet?

Comment: @charleh i dont think that would work here, just by grouping the employee still wont average each row for that employee

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
select employee,
       avg(case when n.n = 1 and rating1 > 0 then rating1
                when n.n = 2 and rating2 > 0 then rating2
                when n.n = 3 and rating3 > 0 then rating3
                when n.n = 4 and rating4 > 0 then rating4
                when n.n = 5 and rating5 > 0 then rating5
           end)
from CSEReduxResponses c cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ) n
where month(c.approveddate)= 6 and year(c.approveddate)=2014
group by employee;
```

I would recommend rewriting the `where` clause as:

```
where c.approveddate >= '2014-06-01' and c.approveddate < '2014-07-01'
```

This would allow the SQL engine to use an index on `approveddate`.

Comment: thanks , but with this is doesnt count where a rating=0 which should not count toward the average

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
(sum(rating1)+sum(rating2)+sum(rating3)+sum(rating4)+sum(rating5))
/
(count(nullif(rating1,0))+count(nullif(rating2,0))+count(nullif(rating3,0))+count(nullif(rating4,0))+count(nullif(rating5,0))) 
as avg_rating,
count(*) as number_of_responses, employee 
From CSEReduxResponses where month(approveddate)= 6 AND year(approveddate)=2014 group by employee ;
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: i've re-written it not to use the IF. Both the original and the new version work for me. What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: i have sql server 2008

Comment: it seems somehow its diving by zero, i know none of the rating1-5 are null but they can all be zero , 
Divide by zero error encountered.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: This suggests to me that your table has data that doesnt quite follow the example you have given.  All of the solutions supplied work for me on the table created using the CREATE statement you gave. Did you try the other sollution i wrote?

Answer (score 0):

I have also come come up with a slightly slicker version, using a UDF. I prefer this one, as the average function might come in useful for other queries...

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS cca_wip.avg_ignore0//
CREATE FUNCTION cca_wip.avg_ignore0(
  str VARCHAR(500)
) RETURNS double
    COMMENT 'values separated by a coma, that are to be averaged. 0 will be treated as NULL'

BEGIN
  DECLARE ss TEXT;
  DECLARE sum, count double;

IF length(str)=0 or str not regexp '[0-9]' then RETURN 0;
end if;

IF str regexp '[a-z]' then RETURN NULL;
end if;

SET str=replace(str,'NULL','0');
SET sum =0;
SET count =0;

WHILE length(str)>0 DO
    set ss=substring_index(str,',',1);
    SET sum = sum + ss;

    IF ss>0 THEN SET count = count+1;
    END IF;

    set str=trim(trim(trim(',') from trim(trim(ss from str))));
END WHILE;

RETURN (sum/count);
END//

DELIMITER ;

select
avg_ignore0(group_concat(concat_ws(',',rating1,rating2,rating3,rating4,rating5))),
count(*)  as number_of_responses, 
employee
From CSEReduxResponses
where 
month(approveddate)= 6 AND  year(approveddate)=2014
group by employee ;
```